# Blue screen of death appears with STOP 0xC2 caused by picadm freeing a cached memory managed region

Tags: bsod

Picadm is a system driver written by us. We have enabled special pool to make sure the Blue screen happens at the point of corruption.

Blue screen happens with following information:

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

BAD_POOL_CALLER (c2)
The current thread is making a bad pool request.  Typically this is at a bad IRQL level or double freeing the same allocation, etc.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000007, Attempt to free pool which was already freed
Arg2: 0000000000001097, (reserved)
Arg3: 0000000000210007, Memory contents of the pool block
Arg4: fffff8a004b98e00, Address of the block of pool being deallocated*

Above information shows that fffff8a004b98e00 is being freed twice leading to BSOD. Since special pool is enabled, we can check the allocations and frees history for this memory address. It gives following result:

```
*2: kd>  !verifier 0x80 fffff8a0`04b98e00
Log of recent kernel pool Allocate and Free operations:
There are up to 0x10000 entries in the log.
Parsing 0x0000000000010000 log entries, searching for address 0xfffff8a004b98e00.
======================================================================
Pool block fffff8a004b98df0, Size 0000000000000210, Thread fffffa80122674f0
fffff80001b0bc9a nt!VfFreePoolNotification+0x4a
fffff800017a367c nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x126d
fffff8000165b880 nt!MiDeleteSegmentPages+0x35c
fffff8000195cf2f nt!MiSegmentDelete+0x7b
fffff80001637e07 nt!MiCleanSection+0x2f7
fffff80001676754 nt!ObfDereferenceObject+0xd4
fffff80001661170 nt!CcDeleteSharedCacheMap+0x1bc
fffff80001699880 nt!CcUninitializeCacheMap+0x2f0
fffff880030ecfa6 picadm!OwCommonCleanup+0x4b6
fffff880030ec840 picadm!FsdCleanup+0x2a8
fffff880030ec994 picadm!OwFsdCleanup+0x38
fffff80001b16750 nt!IovCallDriver+0xa0
fffff800019824bf nt!IopCloseFile+0x11f
======================================================================
Pool block fffff8a004b98df0, Size 0000000000000210, Thread fffffa80122674f0
fffff80001b0bc9a nt!VfFreePoolNotification+0x4a
fffff800017a367c nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x126d
fffff8000165b880 nt!MiDeleteSegmentPages+0x35c
fffff8000195cf2f nt!MiSegmentDelete+0x7b
fffff80001637e07 nt!MiCleanSection+0x2f7
fffff80001676754 nt!ObfDereferenceObject+0xd4
fffff80001661170 nt!CcDeleteSharedCacheMap+0x1bc
fffff80001699880 nt!**CcUninitializeCacheMap**+0x2f0
fffff880030ecfa6 picadm!OwCommonCleanup+0x4b6
fffff880030ec840 picadm!FsdCleanup+0x2a8
fffff880030ec994 picadm!OwFsdCleanup+0x38
fffff80001b16750 nt!IovCallDriver+0xa0
fffff800019824bf nt!IopCloseFile+0x11f*
```

Above shows that this address is deleted twice.

Query : It seems pretty strange to me that both thw stack trace are exactly same. Even the thread is same. What are the possible reasons of this happening. I checked the code involved in the stack trace and cannot find any while/do/for or jump statement leading to execution of the **CcUninitializeCacheMap** twice.

Below is the thread stack at the time BSOD happened. This is the same thread from where delete has happened:

```
*2: kd> !thread fffffa80122674f0 7
THREAD fffffa80122674f0  Cid 3de4.41b8  Teb: 000007fffffac000 Win32Thread: fffff900c0ad4850 RUNNING on processor 3
IRP List:
    fffffa800a3f1240: (0006,0118) Flags: 00000404  Mdl: 00000000
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 fffff8a00fce5bc0
Owning Process            fffffa8015ca0060       Image:         mstsc.exe
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
Wait Start TickCount      104601006      Ticks: 0
Context Switch Count      27964                 LargeStack
UserTime                  00:00:01.375
KernelTime                00:00:07.015
Win32 Start Address 0x000007feef84af90
Stack Init fffff8801406edb0 Current fffff8801406e300
Base fffff8801406f000 Limit fffff88014066000 Call 0
Priority 13 BasePriority 10 UnusualBoost 1 ForegroundBoost 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
fffff880`1406e3d0 fffff880`0312a75a : 00ffffff`00100011 00000000`0000002b fffff880`03166f88 fffff880`0313000e : picadm!CDF_TraceRoutine+0x401 [p:\src\ica\hostcore\workstation\picadm\win64\retail\obj\pdm.tmh @ 4193]
fffff880`1406e530 fffff880`03146d9e : 00ffffff`00100011 00000000`0000000e fffff880`03166f88 fffff880`031590a0 : picadm!WPP_SF_sq+0xba [p:\src\ica\hostcore\workstation\picadm\win64\retail\obj\directory.tmh @ 837]
fffff880`1406e5a0 fffff880`0313674d : fffff980`3a7ecec0 00000000`00000017 fffff880`03166d50 fffff880`031587b0 : picadm!PdmObjectWriteLock+0x6e [p:\src\ica\hostcore\workstation\picadm\pdmobject.cpp @ 175]
fffff880`1406e5f0 fffff880`0313e968 : fffff980`3a7ecec0 00000000`00076615 fffff880`03166f30 fffff880`03158b30 : picadm!NodeReleaseShare+0xcd [p:\src\ica\hostcore\workstation\picadm\node.cpp @ 529]
fffff880`1406e650 fffff880`03101f56 : 00000000`00076615 00000000`00000001 fffff980`bf03cf50 fffff880`0311f0cd : picadm!PdmFsdRemoveShareAccess+0x128 [p:\src\ica\hostcore\workstation\picadm\pdm.cpp @ 3541]
fffff880`1406e6b0 fffff880`030e6943 : 00000000`00000000 fffff980`c3fe4f30 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : picadm!OwRemoveShareAccessFsd+0xfe [h:\devtrees\fsdk_osr\fsdksrc\v1\src\wrapper\fsdsup.cpp @ 4729]
fffff880`1406e760 fffff880`030ed373 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : picadm!OwRemoveShareAccess+0xf7 [h:\devtrees\fsdk_osr\fsdksrc\v1\src\wrapper\misc.cpp @ 1985]
fffff880`1406e7f0 fffff880`030ec840 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`15ca0060 fffff880`03175e00 : picadm!OwCommonCleanup+0x883 [h:\devtrees\fsdk_osr\fsdksrc\v1\src\wrapper\cleanup.cpp @ 1294]
fffff880`1406e8e0 fffff880`030ec994 : 00000000`b1040100 fffff980`c3fe4f30 fffffa80`057c3e40 fffff880`1406e9e8 : picadm!FsdCleanup+0x2a8 [h:\devtrees\fsdk_osr\fsdksrc\v1\src\wrapper\cleanup.cpp @ 255]
fffff880`1406e9a0 fffff800`01b16750 : fffffa80`0a3f1240 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`057c3e01 fffff980`33124fc0 : picadm!OwFsdCleanup+0x38 [h:\devtrees\fsdk_osr\fsdksrc\v1\src\wrapper\cleanup.cpp @ 364]
fffff880`1406e9d0 fffff800`019824bf : fffffa80`0a3f1240 fffffa80`15ca0060 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`07419090 : nt!IovCallDriver+0xa0
fffff880`1406ea30 fffff800`01968384 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`15ca0060 fffff880`1406eae0 00000000`00000018 : nt!IopCloseFile+0x11f
fffff880`1406eac0 fffff800`01981fb1 : fffffa80`15ca0060 fffffa80`00000001 fffff8a0`11e650d0 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObpDecrementHandleCount+0xb4
fffff880`1406eb40 fffff800`01981ec4 : 00000000`00000570 fffffa80`15ca0060 fffff8a0`11e650d0 00000000`00000570 : nt!ObpCloseHandleTableEntry+0xb1
fffff880`1406ebd0 fffff800`016707d3 : fffffa80`122674f0 fffff880`1406eca0 00000000`063d7240 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObpCloseHandle+0x94
fffff880`1406ec20 00000000`7764f7aa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13 (TrapFrame @ fffff880`1406ec20)
00000000`0483eab8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7764f7aa*
```

Please any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Any sort of loop could cause the same stack trace for the two deallocations. P.S. Nice choice of owning process image name!

Comment: Thanks Neil for looking into this. But I checked the code involved in the stack trace and couldn't find any sort loop involved! Do you know any other reason for this?

Comment: No, sorry, a loop was the only idea I had.

Answer (score 0):

Reentrancy can cause this issue. The OS calls your handler more than once on different occasions (I assume it's part of file closing scenario). For example, it's very possible you try to refer to an already closed file handler for the second call - or some other bug of that kind. Check your internal resources management.